# How to add permissions to a new API with STRAPI (not from dashboard)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendmail, sendgrid, strapi

I need to do a new api in order to send an email with sendgrid. I followed the official doc and other examples so I did:

**config/plugins**

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  email: {
    provider: 'sendgrid',
    providerOptions: {
      apiKey: env('SENDGRID_API_KEY'),
    },
    settings: {
      defaultFrom: 'juliasedefdjian@strapi.io',
      defaultReplyTo: 'juliasedefdjian@strapi.io',
    },
  },
});
```

then I did a new folder named *email* in api folder

**api/email/config/routes.json**

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "method": "POST",
      "path": "/email",
      "handler": "email.index",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

finally under **api/email/controllers/email.js**

```
const { default: createStrapi } = require('strapi');

module.exports = {
  index: async (ctx) => {
    //build email with data from ctx.request.body

    await createStrapi.plugins['email'].services.email.send({
      to: 'email@email.com',
      from: 'email@email.com',
      replyTo: 'email@email.com',
      subject: 'test',
      text: 'test',
    });
ctx.send('Email sent!');
  },
};
```

The real problem is that /email api returns me a  403 even if I did this from the dashboard:

[image]

I have done many APIs with strapi but I have never sent emails with it.

Is there a way to add permissions from the code? I have to say that if I use **GET** method it works, but I need to do it with a **POST** method, which doesn't. Did I miss something?

Comment: This error could occur if the *FROM* address is not verified by the sendgrid. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61149142/node-js-sendgrid-mail-403-forbidden-error)  help?

Comment: Yes thank you Singh! There was something wrong with Sendgrid!